# .htaccess - fixing duplicate content issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Some pages are showing up as duplicate content when I run a page crawl with seoMOZ.

for example:

```
/index.php
```

and

```
/index.php/
```

are being crawled as two separate pages. How I would implement a mod-rewrite to remove trailing slashes from only .php files?

Also

```
mysite.com/dir/
```

and

```
mysite.com/dir/index.php
```

are being flagged as duplicate content. I would prefer to have all "/dir/file.php" links redirected to "/dir/" for aesthetic reasons, but I'm not sure of how to do this or if it is the best thing to do from an SEO standpoint.

Thanks for help and advice.

Comment: Just always use the correct url's in your html. Search engines won't try to guess urls. They only use urls you provide. The only problem could be links to your site by others, but those other people first have to guess alternative urls first. Thirdly, search engines are smart enough to know some kinds of urls will return the same content. e.g. `/folder`, `/folder/index`, `/folder/index.php`, `/folder/index.php/whatever`, `/folder/?whatever`, `/folder/index.php?whatever`. This duplicated content is not as much an issue as most people think. I personally don't really worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

An couple ideas:

Add a rel="canonical" link to the  section of the non-canonical version of each HTML page.

Taken from http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

This means that you can set only one page to be the "orginal" or "authoritative" page to be indexed instead of the  pages that contain the same content. This is great for pages that show posts by tags, for example.

ALSO

You can do a redirect. Crack open you htaccess and redirect all inquiries with a query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) $1?
```

There are a lot of ways to handle this, however.